# Did C++11 introduce a case-insensitive string comparison algorithm?

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, stl

Just moved to C++11 on GCC 4.8 and would be nice to move away from `boost::iequals` in favor of STL. I searched around the interwebs but I didn't see any signs of `std::iequals` or new `std::basic_string` methods to support this natively in STL.

If this doesn't exist in C++11, has the approach to solving this problem changed since C++03 (i.e. different workarounds?), or is boost still preferred here?

Thanks in advance.`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, C++11 did not introduce a case-insensitive string comparison function. You'll need to stick with Boost for now.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

There is not native string comparison but with a rich STL you can write your own very simply something like this :

`

```
bool caseInsensitiveCmp(wstring str1, wstring str2)
    {
        if ( str1.size() != str2.size())
            return false;
        else
        return (str1.empty() | str2.empty()) ? 
                false :
                std::equal(str1.begin(), str1.end(),str2.begin(),
                    [](wchar_t a, wchar_t b)
                    {
                        return tolower(a) == tolower(b);
                    }
                );
    }`
```

First check is to guard std:equals from comparing on indifferent length.